# My MVC5 project cant work toghter with WebAPI2 on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

on Visual Studio 2012 update 5:
I have created MVC5 project, 
I have also created WebAPI2 project
Both working fine alone. When I try to combine them to one project - It doesn't work for the webAPI2.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}

    public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);    
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to change the routing ordering.
What happens is that the website goes online first so that the api is blocked.
To fix it need to change the order of the Application_Start

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);    
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    }
```